# Limits and sequences of functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let the sequence of functions {$f_n$} define in [0,1] $\subset$ $\mathbb R$, where $f_{n}=nx^{n}(1-x^{n}), $ $\forall$x $\in$ [0,1]. Proof that:

$\lim\limits_{n}\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}(x)dx$ $\neq$ $\int_{0}^{1}\lim\limits_{n}f_{n}(x)dx$

Comment: Could you please tell us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Hi @APCorreia. I put my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt is the following:

$\lim\limits_{n}\int_{0}^{1}f_ndx$ = $\lim\limits_{n}\int_{0}^{1}nx^{n}(1-x^{n})$

$\lim\limits_{n}[n(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+1})]$

$\lim\limits_{n}\frac{n}{n+1}-\lim\limits_{n}\frac{1}{2n+1}$ = -1/2

$\lim\limits_{n}\int_{0}^{1}f_ndx$ = -1/2

The sencond part:

$\int_{0}^{1}\lim\limits_{n}f_ndx$ = $\int_{0}^{1}\lim\limits_{n}nx^{n}(1-x^{n})$ = not answer

I have trouble with the latest equation.

Comment: The left hand side should be $\frac12$, since the third line should be $$\lim\limits_{n}\frac{n}{n+1}-\lim\limits_{n}\frac{\color{red}n}{2n+1} = \color{red}+\frac12$$